# Ordenar consulta MySQL pelos últimos 3 meses

Tags: php, mysql, sql, order-by

Desejo fazer uma consulta SQL ordenada pelos primeiros 3 meses a partir do mês atual, exemplo:

Mês atual é Agosto (08), então ordeno como:

```
10
9
8
1
12
```

Estou usando o seguinte comando:

```
SELECT * FROM `tb_convencao` WHERE `lg_historico` = 0 ORDER BY (`desc_database`) >= MONTH(now()) DESC, (`desc_database`) < date_add(MONTH(now()), interval 3 month)
```

Mas me é retornado:

```
10
12
8
9
1
```

Alguma dica?

Comment: A pergunta não faz sentido. O que é ordenado pelos últimos três meses? Ordenação não tem condição. Dê mais informações de como está composta a tabela, do conteúdo e resultado esperado, além de explicar melhor o objetivo. A ordem deve ser por qual coluna? Ou nem precisa de ordem? Deve haver um filtro que só pegue só as linhas dos últimos 3 meses? Quais os tipos das colunas?

Comment: O campo `lg_historico` é date?

Comment: Desculpem-me, o campo lg_historico e desc_database são int(11).

Comment: Para ordenar corretamente utilizando datas, são campo deve ser date e não int, apenas alterando o tipo de dado do campo seu problema deve ser resolvido.

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente é isto que precisa mas não garanto já que a pergunta está confusa:

```
SELECT * FROM `tb_convencao` WHERE `lg_historico` = 0 AND
    `desc_database` >= MONTH(now()) - 3
    ORDER BY `desc_database` DESC
```

Se quiser os próximos 3 meses:

```
SELECT * FROM `tb_convencao` WHERE `lg_historico` = 0 AND
    `desc_database` >= MONTH(now()) AND
    `desc_database` <= MONTH(now()) + 3
    ORDER BY `desc_database` DESC
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Last3Months.sql).

Se quer mostrar os próximos 3 meses em primeiro lugar e depois todo o resto, faça uma seleção com estes meses e depois outra seleção com os demais. Se quiser que tudo esteja em consulta única, basta usar um [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html).

Comment: é quase isso...
Me é retornado: 
_desc_database_ 
12 - 10 - 9 - 8 - 2 - 1

Entretanto como estamos em Agosto, queria que fosse ordenado até novembro (11), então o 12 não estaria ordenado na primeira posição.

Comment: Eu cometi um deslize, vê se resolveu. Mas só com as informações passadas fica difícil ajudar mais que isto.

Comment: eu me expressei mal na pergunta mesmo, desculpe. 

Na verdade com _where_ não adianta para mim, pois os outros valores também devem aparecer na listagem. 

Só que o ponto é que eu quero os valores data_base >= `MONTH(now())+3` no topo da listagem

Comment: Ordenação não é filtro, não dá para filtrar a ordenação. Ou você vai ter que filtrar ou vai ter que fazer mais de uma seleção para ter o resto. Ou ainda explicar melhor o que quer.